# PHP Laravel :Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Here is the error message-

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController] does not exist. in file E:\src\Laravel\laravel1\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 835
```

**I'm using PHP version 7.4.4, Laravel Framework 8.37.0**
These things I have already done

1. I have added this line on the top of the controller - `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`
2. In the Routes - api.php

   Route::post('register',[UserController::class,'register']);

Also on the top of this file,I have added this line

```
use App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your UserController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\User\UserRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

class UserController extends Controller {

}
```

Comment: Just tried what you've suggested, but still facing same issue. Thanks

Comment: How about **namespace App\Http\Controllers;** and **use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;** do you have in your controller?

Comment: Yes, These were missing. Just added these namespaces and run cleared route cache again and run the dump-autoload command. Still giving me same error

Comment: In Laravel-8 the routes are changed from **Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');** to **Route::get('/',[UserController::class, 'index']);** and use this in your web.php **use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;**

Comment: that too doesn't help.

Comment: I have edited my answer use the above code in your UserController and remove this **use App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController;**

Comment: Ok, now error has changed -BadMethodCallException: Method App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController::register does not exist.

Comment: @AnoopSingh First check your routes and again use your own controller and get those things from my answer that don't exist in your answer.

Comment: Instead of using **use App\Http\Controllers\User\UserController;** you have namespace no need do call again **namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;**